# How to show a file in a Details view in asp.NET MVC4 web application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, detailsview

I am working on an asp.NET MVC4 web application. I have a create view with Upload file (CV). I succeeded to upload the file correctly but I need to show it (the CV) in the Details view and i don't know how to do it.
Here's the class :

```
 public class Consultant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CIN { get; set; }
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    public string Prenom { get; set; }
    public string RefCommercial { get; set; }

  [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public string DateNaissance { get; set; }

    public string Fonction { get; set; }
    public string Tel { get; set; }
    public string Experience { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string CVurl { get; set; }
```

The attribute CVurl contains the file's name.
Now i want to show the file in the Details view of a consultant.
Any help? Thanks

Comment: I don't think you've thought this through.  What kind of file is it?  Is it plain text?  Is it XML?  Is CSV?  Is it a word document?  PDF?  You can't just "show" many kinds of files, because the contents of those files are unintelligible and only readable by another application that first downloads the file.  Oh, and opencv is about Computer Vision data files, not resumes (which I assume you're talking about given the context here).

Comment: By CV i meant a Curriculum Vitae of a consultant. the file can be either a word document or PDF.

Comment: Yes, I figured that's what you meant... which is why I was pointing out that the opencv tag was not what you thought it was.  We call them Resume's here, not CV's.  In any event, you can't just "show" a word or pdf document in a web page, it has to be downloaded to the user.

Comment: Ok and how can I download it..